# Is it possible to extend Categories in ExpressionEngine 2

Tags: expressionengine

we are currently weighing up what cms to use with Expression Engine 2 being a strong candidate.

We would like to create a bilingual site where the categories would need to be in both languages.

I see that a category has the following fields
Category Name,
Url Title,
Description,
Image url,

We would also like to add "Category Name French" and "Description French" to each category and have them editable via the control panel form.

Does any one know if this is possible?

Any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the standard **ExpressionEngine Category Fields** — *Category Name, Category URL Title, Category Description, Category Image URL* — you can add as many additional [Custom Category Fields](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/content_admin/category_fields_edit.html) as you see necessary.

You can add/edit custom category fields in the ExpressionEngine Control Panel at:

```
Admin > Channel Administration > Categories > Manage Category Fields
```

This would allow you to add your "*Category Name French*" and "*Description French*" fields to each category and have them editable in the Control Panel.

[image: Create New Category Field].

Answer (score 1):

I use category parents to group the individual categories, you can then easily output the required categories based on language, either via the parameter "category_group". You can then use all the default category fields and custom ones.

[image: Categories]

Basically:

English
  -- category 1 (in English)
  -- category 2 (in English)
  -- category 3 (in English)
French
  -- category 1 (in French)
  -- category 2 (in French)
  -- category 3 (in French)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted best practice for multi-lingual sites in EE2 is to use the commercial add-on Transcribe. http://eeharbor.com/transcribe

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution around bilingual categories is writing the name of the second language category in the category description input field and then use {category_description} as the name tag for that language. That is not useful if you need a description for both languages though.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along the same lines. Maybe I could add both to the field and parse them out and show in the view depending on the current language. ie lang1|lang2  then do a split('|') into an array.

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you:

I haven't used EE2.0, but in EE 1.X you could create custom category fields.

Create a "{fr_category_description}" for instance

then have a read at this tutorial - http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/

I implemented this on an english/welsh website and it worked very nicely

URLs look like `site.com/COUNTRY_CODE/template_group/template` and serve content based on this.

works by assigning a variable based on the country, then within your templates you can do:

`<h1>{{country_code}_my_field}</h1>`

which will translate to:

`<h1>{en_my_field}</h1>` for `site.com/en/` or `<h1>{fr_my_field}</h1>` for `site.com/fr`

you just need to create fields with the country code as a prepended and you're good to go.

let me know if you need any clarification, can provide code from my live site.

Comment: might be overkill for your needs though ~